# Calling specific trait implementation on a non-generic struct

Tags: rust, traits

I have a non-generic struct that implements a generic trait.  When I call a function on the struct, I get the following error:

```
error[E0282]: unable to infer enough type information about `_`
  --> src/main.rs:35:18
   |
35 |     cpu.debugger.attach();
   |                  ^^^^^^ cannot infer type for `_`
   |
   = note: type annotations or generic parameter binding required
```

I've tried adding type annotations and generic parameter bindings, but I'm obviously doing something wrong; I still can't get it to compile.  I have similar code elsewhere with a generic struct that works, presumably because the generic-bounds shared by the struct and trait impl allow the compiler to infer the actual method implementation to call.

The best way to illustrate the issue is with a reduced example:

```
struct Cpu<M: Memory, D: Debugger<M>> {
    mem: M,
    debugger: D,
}

impl<M: Memory, D: Debugger<M>> Cpu<M, D> {
    fn new(mem: M, debugger: D) -> Self {
        Cpu {
            mem: mem,
            debugger: debugger,
        }
    }
}

trait Memory {}

struct SimpleMemory;

impl Memory for SimpleMemory {}

trait Debugger<M: Memory> {
    fn attach(&mut self) {}
    fn step(mem: &M) {}
}

struct NoOpDebugger;

impl<M: Memory> Debugger<M> for NoOpDebugger {}

fn main() {
    let mut cpu = Cpu::new(SimpleMemory, NoOpDebugger);
    cpu.debugger.attach(); // <-- cannot infer type for `_`
}
```

Please excuse the poor title, but it's the best way I know how to describe the problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have several options.

1. You can specify on which specific trait you want to invoke the `attach` method.

   ```
   fn main() {
       let mut cpu = Cpu::new(SimpleMemory, NoOpDebugger);
       Debugger::<SimpleMemory>::attach(&mut cpu.debugger);
   }
   ```

   or

   ```
   fn main() {
       let mut cpu = Cpu::new(SimpleMemory, NoOpDebugger);
       <NoOpDebugger as Debugger<SimpleMemory>>::attach(&mut cpu.debugger);
   }
   ```
2. You can move the `attach` method to a supertrait that is not generic.

   ```
   trait DebuggerBase {
       fn attach(&mut self) {}
   }

   trait Debugger<M: Memory>: DebuggerBase {
       fn step(mem: &M) {}
   }

   impl DebuggerBase for NoOpDebugger {}
   impl<M: Memory> Debugger<M> for NoOpDebugger {}
   ```
3. You can add a [`PhantomData`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/marker/struct.PhantomData.html) member to `NoOpDebugger` and make `NoOpDebugger` itself generic, so that each `NoOpDebugger<M>` only implements `Debugger<M>` for the same `M`. In your example, the `M` for `NoOpDebugger` will be inferred from the call to `Cpu::new`.

   ```
   use std::marker::PhantomData;

   struct NoOpDebugger<M>(PhantomData<M>);

   impl<M: Memory> Debugger<M> for NoOpDebugger<M> {}

   fn main() {
       let mut cpu = Cpu::new(SimpleMemory, NoOpDebugger(PhantomData));
       cpu.debugger.attach();
   }
   ```
4. If the implementations of `Debugger` don't depend on `M`, and if you don't use `Debugger` as a trait object, then you can move the type parameter to the methods that need it and omit it on the methods that don't need it.

   ```
   trait Debugger {
       fn attach(&mut self) {}
       fn step<M: Memory>(mem: &M) {}
   }
   ```